# Built-in Wifi not working after upgrade to Jolnir 6.1

Tags: wifi, hp, release-jolnir

I have an old laptop here (HP ProBook from 2014) and have been using ElementaryOS on it since I bought it. Today I installed EOS 6.1 on it.
I had a couple of problems during installation (used custom partitions and forgot the /boot partition), but now I have a running system. However, the built-in wifi does not work. It does not show up in the network settings, only ethernet, vpn, proxy.
I tried with my wifi usb stick and that worked out of the box. But I need that for my computer, so the laptop has to use its own wifi card. It did work before with EOS Hera 5.1.

**A couple of random pieces of information:**

*It's not a dual boot. It's UEFI.*

*Before I used only one partition, this time I wanted to separate data from OS, so I put /home on its own partition.*

*The built-in wifi card is a Broadcom BCM43228. Kernel module is "bcma".*

*I ran apt update and apt dist-upgrade already and restarted after that. No change.*

*I followed some tutorials on the internet and they suggested to install additional drivers (bwml-source something). I did that and during installation they did a modprobe and told me "module wl not found".*

*rfkill list all returns nothing.*

Any ideas? I thought hardware support would be no problem on such an old, but not ancient machine...

**Update August 2023:**

This problem is still persistent (I recently tried it again). Newer ElementaryOS distributions seem to have a lot of [strange problems with wifi connections](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/30209/connection-to-certain-wifi-keeps-dropping-deauthenticating-from-xxx-by-local-ch).