# Connection to certain wifi keeps dropping (deauthenticating from xxx by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING))

Tags: wifi, horus

I upgraded to EOS 7 Horus yesterday (I did a fresh install, before I used 5.1 Hera, I think).

My wifi connection worked out of the box, only to a certain wifi access point it will not connect. I checked dmesg and see this strange message:

```
deauthenticating from xxx by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
```

So it does connect (authenticated, associated), but then disconnects as if I clicked that in the GUI. The access point is old and Hera was an old OS, is it possible that Horus is too new and some kind of legacy protocol is missing? How can I debug that?

Update:

I tried to find out more about debugging wifi connections and managed to find this in journalctl:

```
state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

I noticed in this journalctl log a difference between the working network an the not-working access point: For both there is a record for IPv6. For working, it afterwards goes on to IPv4. For not-working, next message is fail. Maybe there's a problem with Horus preferring IPv6 and my old access point not understanding this?

working:

```
Apr 09 20:26:52 <computer> NetworkManager[794]: <info>  [1681064812.7917] device (<wlan>): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "<working>"
Apr 09 20:26:52 <computer> NetworkManager[794]: <info>  [1681064812.7919] device (<wlan>): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 09 20:26:52 <computer> NetworkManager[794]: <info>  [1681064812.7933] dhcp4 (<wlan>): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Apr 09 20:26:52 <computer> avahi-daemon[791]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface <wlan>.IPv6 with address <computer>.
Apr 09 20:26:52 <computer> avahi-daemon[791]: New relevant interface <wlan>.IPv6 for mDNS.
Apr 09 20:26:52 <computer> avahi-daemon[791]: Registering new address record for <address> on <wlan>.*.
Apr 09 20:26:52 <computer> NetworkManager[794]: <info>  [1681064812.8618] dhcp4 (<wlan>): state changed new lease, address=192.168.0.20
Apr 09 20:26:52 <computer> avahi-daemon[791]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface <wlan>.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.20.
Apr 09 20:26:52 <computer> avahi-daemon[791]: New relevant interface <wlan>.IPv4 for mDNS.
Apr 09 20:26:52 <computer> avahi-daemon[791]: Registering new address record for 192.168.0.20 on <wlan>.IPv4.
Apr 09 20:26:52 <computer> NetworkManager[794]: <info>  [1681064812.8631] device (<wlan>): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

not-working:

```
Apr 09 20:26:17 <computer> NetworkManager[794]: <info>  [1681064777.8237] device (<wlan>): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "<not-working>"
Apr 09 20:26:17 <computer> NetworkManager[794]: <info>  [1681064777.8239] device (<wlan>): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 09 20:26:17 <computer> NetworkManager[794]: <info>  [1681064777.8244] dhcp4 (<wlan>): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Apr 09 20:26:17 <computer> avahi-daemon[791]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface <wlan>.IPv6 with address <address>.
Apr 09 20:26:17 <computer> avahi-daemon[791]: New relevant interface <wlan>.IPv6 for mDNS.
Apr 09 20:26:17 <computer> avahi-daemon[791]: Registering new address record for <address> on <wlan>.*.
Apr 09 20:26:18 <computer> wpa_supplicant[831]: <wlan>: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-49 noise=9999 txrate=14400
Apr 09 20:26:19 <computer> gala[1582]: clutter_animatable_get_actor: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_ANIMATABLE (animatable)' failed
Apr 09 20:26:19 <computer> gala[1582]: clutter_animatable_get_actor: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_ANIMATABLE (animatable)' failed
Apr 09 20:26:30 <computer> systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 09 20:26:49 <computer> NetworkManager[794]: <info>  [1681064809.7166] device (<wlan>): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

UPDATE:

```
  *-network                 
       Beschreibung: Ethernet interface
       Produkt: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       Hersteller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       [...]
       Konfiguration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.19.0-38-generic firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       Ressourcen: irq:18 ioport:d000(Größe=256) memory:d0004000-d0004fff memory:d0000000-d0003fff
  *-network
       Beschreibung: Kabellose Verbindung
       [...]
       Fähigkeiten: ethernet physical wireless
       Konfiguration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb driverversion=5.19.0-38-generic firmware=0.36 ip=192.168.0.20 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

Maybe I should add that this is a USB device. This is from lsusb -v:

```
ID 2001:3c15 D-Link Corp. DWA-140 RangeBooster N Adapter(rev.B3) [Ralink RT5372]
```

So it seems like I don't need a Realtek, but a Ralink driver. Like [this one](https://wiki.debian.org/rt2800usb)

**UPDATE August 2023:**

This problem is still not solved although the OS is now months old and there were many updates. I am still looking for help with this.

Comment: This looks like an incorrect driver issue. Could you [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lshw -C network`? This will show your current device and which driver is being used. It should be possible to confirm correctness from there 

Comment: @matigo thanks, I added the info you requested. hope that helps debugging

Comment: That's odd. [According to Linux Hardware](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:2001-3c15), that device works without any issues.

Comment: @matigo it does work. Just not with that one access point/repeater. Do you have any other idea what i can try or check?